# combining upload picture with registration

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to make a registration form in which the user should be able to upload the profile picture along with the registration form . I am uploading the picture using ajax like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#UploadForm').on('submit', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#SubmitButton').attr('disabled', ''); // disable upload button
         //show uploading message
         $("#profile_picture").html('<div class ="update_load" style="padding:10px"><img class="load_pic" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Please Wait"/> </div>');
         $(this).ajaxSubmit({
             target: '#profile_picture',
             success: afterSuccess //call function after success
         });
     });
 });
```

the feedback from the ajax is the picture like this

```
echo '<img class="profile" src="uploads/'.$name.'.'.$ext.'" >';
```

Now i want to transfer the $name variable on the other process.php file to my current index.php file so that i can insert it using the MySQL Query . i dont know how to do that . And my second question is that if a user changes his picture more than once in the registration form , how would i delete all of his previous uploads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, this is what I do and I believe that can help you:

1) generate a timestamp + randon number > **magic number**

2) use uploadify jquery plugin to upload the photo to a temp folder (*you can upload photos from the same form where the user completes personal data*)

3) save that file with the magic number as the name (*you can upload as many as you want over writing the previous one*)

4) POST that generated number along with the rest of your form with the user data

choose a number 5):

5a) When saving the data, simply rename the temp file to a final folder with your new id from mysql

5b) leave the temp file as it is, just move it to a final folder and use the magic number to store it in your database

hope this helps!

Comment: confused with some steps . 1st , i am using ajax to upload the picture to a folder and viewing it back at the same time using the ajax . 1st problem is to get that magic number back to my main register.php page . second , the magic number would be different every time so how would i over write each previous picture . and third , how to i post a number along with a form ?

Comment: I generate it when I load the page and fill a hidden input with that number. It will also be availabe for you to send it to the script where you upload the photo

Comment: Thanks mate.. That helped . i got one more question . if the user upload one or two pics but don't complete the registration and refreshes the page to start over. What do i do with the previously uploaded picture ? what do I do about that ?

Comment: You could have some script that delete all photos in the temp folder that are x days old.

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't need 2 separate forms. You can do everthing in just one form and submit everything at once (whith previous image upload)

Comment: bro how would i send ajax request to process.php and data to register.php through the same form ? wouldn't i require two forms for that ?

Comment: n one more thing . I can generate a magic number and enter it to the Mysql query but how would i know the file extension of the uploaded picture ? which would be required later

Answer (score 1):

You can write an afterSuccess   function taking  response as parameter.

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
             target: '#profile_picture',
             success: afterSuccess(data) //call function after success
         });

function afterSuccess(data)
{
    //parse your response to take the name
    //make another ajax request to save it to database
}
```

This function can handle the new picture uploads too.
You will make that checks in php level (the ajax called)

Parse the img string to take src like that:

```
var img = $('<img class="profile" src="uploads/gaidouri.jpg" />');
var src = $(img).attr('src');
```

Comment: 2 questions : .. 1st is the i already am using a afterSuccess function to reset the upload form . And the responce is a whole <img> block . so how do i handle that . And second thing is that on my registration.php page where i am uploading the picture , i cannot save the picture because the user has not been entered yet in the database . it would only be added after submitting the form . i just want to transfer a variable from my process.php to my register.php and then use it in the php block not the jquery script block.

Comment: 1st is answered in my edit, above.
About the 2nd, you mean that you have 2 forms?? Why? You can do the whole thing in one form.

Comment: #2: If it is about showing a preview or something, as Mantis said you can use a hidden input to keep src and set its value on afterSuccess.
Then you can take that value easily on submit registration form.

Comment: yup . I need 2 forms because with one form , i am uploading the picture and with the second form , i am submitting the query for Mysql with member data . they both point to two different php files